# 'PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions' after upgrading to firebase-admin 5.13.0

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

After upgrading to firebase-admin 5.13.0 I'm consistently getting the following error when trying to write to firestore.

```
'PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions'
```

My rules are set to:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I believe this should allow all writes. If I downgrade to 5.12.0 everything works normally. Is this a bug in firebase-admin 5.13.0 or has the behavior changed?

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior, from code that has worked perfectly fine for months unchanged. Very frustrating.

Comment: This is most likely caused by the following issue: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/277. A fix is in progress. Once a new version of the Firestore client gets released with the fix, simply reinstalling `firebase-admin` should do the trick. In the meantime, please stick to `firebase-admin` 5.12.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We published a new release to address your issue. Please upgrade to the latest `@google-cloud/firestore` (v0.15.4).

Comment: That seems to be working now with `@google-cloud/firestore 0.15.4` and `firebase-admin 5.13.0` . Thanks very much for the swift response